# Outlook 2013 Inline Response

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, addin-express

I have a question about Outlook 2013 and Inline Response.
I have created an advanced formregion with the "AddIn Express" extension for VSTO and this is always visible when I open the compose window to write a message. So far, everything is fine. But when I reply to a message, my formregion is not visible anymore. I think the problem is the Inline response.
Are there any possibilities to show my formregion in the inline response window ?

thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest contacting Add-in Express guys to make sure that an inline response feature is supported by advanced form regions.